# obtener nombre del archivo en una ruta con c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo una ruta "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\archivo.xlsx" pero solo quiero obtener el nombre del archivo, estoy usando indexOf en c# pero no puedo consehuir el nombre

```html
String cadena = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\archivo.xlsx";
Int32 index = cadena.Trim().IndexOf("\");
String cadenaDerecha = cadena.Substring(0,index)
```

Comment: Lo tienes asi \Users\PC\Desktop\archivo.xlsx en vez de \\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\archivo.xlsx?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez si, es que obtengo esa ruta de un label, pero solo quiero el nombre del archivo ya que lo inserto en una BD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reutilizando tu códificación:

Utiliza la clase FileInfo, para ello agrega el siguiente using:

```
using System.IO
```

y usa la siguiente línea para trabajar con las propiedades del archivo.

```
String cadena = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\archivo.xlsx";
FileInfo fi= new FileInfo(cadena);
```

El nombre lo obtienes llamando a la propiedad Name, te lo devuelve con extensión.

```
var nombre = fi.Name;
```

y sin extensión debes usar el objeto Path

```
var nombre = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name);
```

Espero que te sirva

Saludos

Comment: gracias justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: de nada, saludos